# Can I use type annotations of class to make decision about result type of method of the class?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have some with two inheritors.

```scala
trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]] {
  this: T =>
}

class MyTraitImpl1 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl1]
class MyTraitImpl2 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl2]
```

These inheritors are mutually exclusive and can be derived from each other so there is another class typed with `MyTrait`.

```scala
class TypedClass[T <: MyTrait](value: T) {

  def anotherValue[O <: MyTrait]: O
}
```

Can I do something to make method `anotherValue` return exactly `MyTraitImpl1` if `TypedClass` is typed with `MyTraitImpl2` and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can modify `MyTrait`, `MyTraitImpl1`, `MyTraitImpl2` you can add type member `OtherType`

```
  trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]] {
    this: T =>
    type OtherType <: MyTrait[_]
  }

  class MyTraitImpl1 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl1] {
    override type OtherType = MyTraitImpl2
  }
  class MyTraitImpl2 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl2] {
    override type OtherType = MyTraitImpl1
  }


  class TypedClass[T <: MyTrait[T]](value: T) {

    def anotherValue: T#OtherType = ???
  }

//    OR
//  class TypedClass[T <: MyTrait[T]](val value: T) {
//
//    def anotherValue: value.OtherType = ???
//  }

  new TypedClass[MyTraitImpl1](new MyTraitImpl1).anotherValue : MyTraitImpl2
  new TypedClass[MyTraitImpl2](new MyTraitImpl2).anotherValue : MyTraitImpl1
//  new TypedClass[MyTraitImpl1](new MyTraitImpl1).anotherValue : MyTraitImpl1 // doesn't compile
//  new TypedClass[MyTraitImpl2](new MyTraitImpl2).anotherValue : MyTraitImpl2 // doesn't compile
```

If you can't modify `MyTrait`, `MyTraitImpl1`, `MyTraitImpl2` you can create type class `OtherType`

```
  trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]] {
    this: T =>
  }

  class MyTraitImpl1 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl1]
  class MyTraitImpl2 extends MyTrait[MyTraitImpl2]

  trait OtherType[T <: MyTrait[T]] {
    type Out <: MyTrait[_]
  }

  object OtherType {
    type Aux[T <: MyTrait[T], Out0 <: MyTrait[_]] = OtherType[T] { type Out = Out0 }
    def instance[T <: MyTrait[T], Out0 <: MyTrait[_]]: Aux[T, Out0] = new OtherType[T] { type Out = Out0 }

    implicit val otherType1: Aux[MyTraitImpl1, MyTraitImpl2] = instance
    implicit val otherType2: Aux[MyTraitImpl2, MyTraitImpl1] = instance
  }

  class TypedClass[T <: MyTrait[T]](value: T) {

    def anotherValue(implicit otherType: OtherType[T]): otherType.Out = ???
  }
```